# External Control of System or Configuration Setting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, database-connection, connection-string, veracode

(Sorry, if this is a dumb question....)

Veracode reports my website has a security issue which relates to use connection string from web.config.

Here is my code.

```
Public Function ExecuteScalar(ByVal sql As String) As Object
    Dim obj As Object = Nothing

    Try
        Dim connStr as String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("mydatabase").ConnectionString
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)   '''Veracode reports the issue come from this line
            conn.Open()
            If conn IsNot Nothing Then
                '''execute my sql
            End If
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try

    Return obj
End Function
```

Veracode said:

> This call to
>   system_data_dll.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.!newinit_0_1()
>   allows external control of system settings. The argument to the
>   function is constructed using user-supplied input, which can disrupt
>   service or cause an application to behave in unexpected ways. The
>   first argument to !newinit_0_1() contains tainted data from the
>   variable connStr. The tainted data originated from earlier calls to
>   system_web_dll.system.web.httprequest.get_item,
>   system_data_dll.system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fill,
>   system_data_dll.system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar, and
>   fmmobile8_dll.virtualcontroller.vc_wcfentry.

Remediation:

> Never allow user-supplied or otherwise untrusted data to control
>   system-level settings. Always validate user-supplied input to ensure
>   that it conforms to the expected format, using centralized data
>   validation routines when possible.

The same isuse was reported by CWE: http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/15.html

OK, the suggestion from Veracode said that I should check the format of connection string before using it to create SqlConnection object.

I also asked Google professor about how to check format of connection string. But the returned results said that we should create SqlConnection object, then open it.

If the response is OK, the connection string also means a valid format. Otherwise, the connection string is invalid.

Unfortunately, Veracode does not accept this answer.

So, my question is that:

Should we check the format of connection string before creating SqlConnection object (as Veracode said)? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the format of the connection string, it's that it may be controlled by somebody not intended. For instance an attacker may be able to change your web.config and have your application connect to a fake database to serve fake data. Note that such an attacker might be internal to your organization (a disgruntled IT ops employee), or an external attacker that already gained some level of access.

So the question is whether you trust your web.config file according to your threat model. Probably you do for several reasons (you have good processes to mitigate risks), in which case this would be "mitigated by design" in Veracode terms.

Basically it's just a warning to raise attention that web.config is in a sense external to your application and can be changed by more people than you would initially think of, and changing it by unintended people may lead to unwanted results.

Comment: I'd think so in most cases, yes. :)

Comment: 99% of BackEnd services are configured with files to have some kind of flexibility. There should be a way to tell Veracode what files are trusted otherwise CWE-15 alert is totally useless.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue with Veracode and they told me to make sure the Web.config file was encrypted.

You can do this via some command line prompt actions on the server where the application is deployed.

```
 aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/" -site 1
```

or if you wanted to expand your security to the appSettings section

```
 aspnet_regiis -pe "appSettings" -app "/" -site 1
```

You get the site number by opening IIS and going to the Advanced Settings for the site. It is the field labeled "ID"

Here is a MSDN article explaining in more detail:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx